# Android code is needed smileys pop up window

Tags: android

I am developing a chat application. And i want to have pop up window with smileys in it so that when user clicks on one of smileys it will be inserted to edit text box.

Does anyone know sample code for it?

I wanted code for both pop up window and code to embbed smileys in an application. 
(same as in case of yahoo which has smileys.how to code for it and how to store them in database and all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html).  You'll want to use it in similar fashion to this tutorial here:  http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/.

I would populate it with your drawable images, and then attach to each image you create a [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) that would insert the smiley into whatever text window your using.

I'm not an Android expert, and I'm still learning myself, but this is one approach I would investigate.

Comment: Thank u ... I did pop up window ..But problem is that it is stick to layout.when i click on layout i want it to b hidden...as it happens in facebook o any other messangers. But in my case pop up window is stick to layout .

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you want something that will only take up a small section of space on the activity(?).  Something like a quickaction - http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/ ?  Ultimately it sounds like a dialog, then populated with icons for smileys.

Comment: i wanted dismissal of pop up window on clicking on layout. thnks in advance